# How to get administrator rights as administrator?

Tags: windows-10

Windows 10. Trying to copy a file from desktop to `C:\`. Why do I ALWAYS have to press *Continue* when I want to do such a small and easy task as copying a file?

I am already administrator, but yet it asks for administrator permissions. I always want to start EVERYTHING with administrator rights automatically, how do I do that?

[image: UAC]

Comment: Note- `C:\\`  is proper form. (and note, superuser can eat backslashes)

Comment: @barlop for some reason I didn't see that :)

Comment: I know, originally I typed `C:[backslash]` but it got translated to `C:.`. That's why I changed it to a forward slash instead...

Comment: @Sindragooosa stackexchange sites eat a backslash, you had C:\\. And it ate the backslash. A way to stop it eating the backslash is either do two backslashes, or enclose with backquotes, or highlight and click that button that says 'code'

Answer (score 1):

Moving the `User Account Control Settings` slider to the bottom, does not turn off UAC, it just tells Windows to `never notify` you when you are elevated.

Because UAC is still on, you can't create a new file in C:\ because explorer.exe runs as the standard user part of your account and users can not create files in C:\

To test for UAC open an un-elevated command prompt and run:

```
whoami -groups
```

if you see `Group used for deny only` as the attributes for `Administrators` UAC is still on.

There is a way to turn off UAC completely, but that should never be the solution.

For once, there should be no files in the root of C:\

If you really have to manage many files for which you have to be an admin, you have two options:

Enable the `administrator` account and log on with it. There is no UAC for it.

Don't use File Explorer for file operations, it's pretty bad at it anyways. Use a third party program to manage your files and elevate it when you need to.

Comment: Adding to that two quick workarounds: Either use an elevated (Power)shell for the copy operation or abuse the file-dialogue of notepad (which can be started with administrative privileges)

Answer (score -1):

1. Click `Change User Account Control Settings` in Users and Groups
2. Slide the slider to `Off`
3. Click `OK`
4. Reboot

Comment: That's the first thing I do every time I install Windows. It doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @Sindragooosa have you rebooted? are you sure UAC is fully off?

Comment: Yes I have rebooted and UAC is fully off: http://i.imgur.com/x33OZPz.png

Comment: You have to disable UAC through a group policy to actually disable it.  This just silently kills the prompt, which, doesn't disable UAC